# Join elimination with columnstore index in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, performance, columnstore

Is there any way to convince SQL Server 2014 to do join elimination when joining columnstore indexed tables?

We have a standard dimensional model, with fact tables and dimensions, and there are views which join the facts with their many dimensions for the convenience of users.

When using conventional row store tables, we can take advantage of SQL's ability to eliminate the joins from those convenience views if they aren't necessary for a given query, by virtue of the fact that there are FK/PK relationships defined between the Facts and the Dimensions which allow the query planner to be certain that the join doesn't add or remove rows.

However, we'd like to convert the fact tables to columnstores, since they have massive performance improvements for the kinds of aggregate queries that are commonly done on the datamarts. But if we do so, we lose the ability to define the foreign keys, given that they aren't supported by columnstores. In turn, this prevents the planner from doing join elimination, making the convenience views do a whole bunch of unnecessary joining in many situations.

Is there any way to convince the planner to do join elimination, without the use of foreign keys?

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge for SQL Server 2014 this is impossible. You can easily get it with SQL Server 2016 Clustered Columnstore and the foreign keys ... :)
In some of the latest Cumulative Updates for SQL Server 2014 RTM & SP1 branches, there is one interesting bug fix that improve some performance, but I do understand that it is not exactly what you are looking for:
[Query plan generation improvement for some columnstore queries in SQL Server 2014 or 2016](https://support.microsoft.com/en-nz/kb/3146123)